# RPM package for GCC snapshot?

Tags: gcc, installation, manifest, archive, rpm

How can I make RPM package for GCC snapshot given the archive file `gcc-7-20170319.tar.bz2`?

How can I force the `make install` command to generate something like `install_manifest.txt` there all the installation commands will be logged?

Answer (score 1):

I would download the standard Fedora specfile for `gcc` and then just tweak it as needed (fix the `Source` for starters).